# depthFirstTraversel with binary search tree

Tags: javascript

I try to get the results of depthFirstTraverselfor with binary search tree. But I get a Blanco output.

So I have this:

```
class BST {
  constructor(value) {
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = value;
  }

  insert(value) {
    if (value <= this.value) {
      if (!this.left) this.left = new BST(value);
      else this.left.insert(value);
    } else if (value > this.value) {
      if (!this.right) this.right = new BST(value);
      else {
        this.right.insert(value);
       
      }
    }
  }


  depthFirstTraversel = (iteratorFunc) => {    
    if (this.left) this.left.depthFirstTraversel(iteratorFunc);  
    if (this.right) this.right.depthFirstTraversel(iteratorFunc);
  };
}

function log(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

const bst = new BST(50);
bst.insert(30);
bst.insert(70);
bst.insert(100);
bst.insert(60);
bst.insert(59);
bst.insert(20);
bst.insert(45);
bst.insert(35);
bst.insert(85);
bst.insert(105);
bst.insert(10);




bst.depthFirstTraversel(log);
```

So what I expect is a ascending order of the numbers:  10 20 30..etc

But I get a Blanco page  back in google chrome dev tools

Comment: You are never actually calling your `iteratorFunc` ( ie log in your case) but just stepping to the next node ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your depthFirstTraversel doesn't try to output anything, all it does is traverse.  You keep passing the `log` function as a parameter, for some reason, but you never call it.

Here's a corrected version (I removed passing the log function as parameter, because it can just be called directly.)

```js
class BST {
  constructor(value) {
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = value;
  }

  insert(value) {
    if (value <= this.value) {
      if (!this.left) this.left = new BST(value);
      else this.left.insert(value);
    } else if (value > this.value) {
      if (!this.right) this.right = new BST(value);
      else {
        this.right.insert(value);
       
      }
    }
  }


  depthFirstTraversel = () => {    
    if (this.left) this.left.depthFirstTraversel();  
    log(this.value);
    if (this.right) this.right.depthFirstTraversel();
  };
}

function log(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

const bst = new BST(50);
bst.insert(30);
bst.insert(70);
bst.insert(100);
bst.insert(60);
bst.insert(59);
bst.insert(20);
bst.insert(45);
bst.insert(35);
bst.insert(85);
bst.insert(105);
bst.insert(10);




bst.depthFirstTraversel(log);
```

Comment: eh, thank you. But the result is not what I expected. What I said, it has to be: ascending order, so: 10, 20, 30, etc

Comment: You asked why it doesn't produce any output, so that's what I answered.

Comment: But also the result. that Is also what I asked.

Comment: To have it in ascending order, you would actually need to output the value *after* traversing the left but *before* traversing the right child

Comment: Thanks @derpischer, I made that change